# Should view logic be abstracted to other modules?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a handful of functions in some of my views that could easily be abstracted away. Looking through the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/), I couldn't find much info on where is the best place to keep them.

So should it go:

**1:** In the view, just abstracted away into another function.

or

**2:** In a new module within the same Django application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would depend on what your views do, if they verify form data, then use `django-forms` to handle the form data, and that can make your code much cleaner. [You can take a look at them here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/).

If you do a lot of things with models, just create a [django `ModelManager`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/) to handle the queries that you always do in your views.

However, if you think that there is a lot of boiler-plate code that does not fit into all of these, then why not use [django CBVs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/class-based-views/) to get rid of having to write boiler-plate code all over again.

It all comes down to what you want.